# Winapi Multiple Windows same WindowProc

Tags: c, winapi

I am developing a GUI with WINAPI and I've a question.
I made a custom progress bar with the respective Procedure for handling it's messages.
I paint the progress bar myself. For the progress bar percentage I use a static variable that I update using a custom message and then I repaint the progress bar by using InvalidateRect.
Now how could I optimize my code so I could create multiple windows of my ProgressBar class.
The problem is that I can't use that same static percentage variable for all of them! So each instance should have it's own percentage variable.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All windows have at least one pointer-sized user data variable that you can use for whatever purpose you like - it is accessed via `GetWindowLongPtr`/`SetWindowLongPtr` with the index `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Additionally, when you register a window class, you can specify additional user data to be allocated for each window in your class, using the `WNDCLASS` member `cbWndExtra`. For example, if you set this to sizeof(DWORD_PTR) when you registered your class, you could also store a DWORD_PTR-sized value using `SetWindowLongPtr` with index 0.

Depending on how much data you want to store per-window, you can store it directly using the above methods, or allocate your own structure and store a pointer to it (remembering to free the data when the window is destroyed).

An additional method of storing data per-window is using window properties via the `SetProp` and `GetProp` functions, which let you store one or more pointer-sized name/value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Dont make the percentage variable static. Make it part of the class and read/write from getter/setters

Comment: Hi I use C and not C++ so I do not program OO